# Best Practices for Cron on Docker

Tags: docker, cron

I've transitioned to using docker with cron for some time but I'm not sure my setup is optimal.  I have one cron container that runs about 12 different scripts.  I can edit the schedule of the scripts but in order to deploy a new version of the software running (some scripts which run for about 1/2 day) I have to create a new container to run some of the scripts while others finish.

I'm considering either running one container per script (the containers will share everything in the image but the crontab).  But this will still make it hard to coordinate updates to multiple containers sharing some of the same code.

The other alternative I'm considering is running cron on the host machine and each command would be a `docker run` command.  Doing this would let me update the next run image by using an environment variable in the `crontab`.

Does anybody have any experience with either of these two solutions?  Are there any other solutions that could help?

Answer (score 3):

If you are just running docker standalone (single host) and need to run a bunch of cron jobs without thinking too much about their impact on the host, then making it simple running them on the host works just fine.

It would make sense to run them in docker if you benefit from docker features like limiting memory and cpu usage (so they don't do anything disruptive). If you also use a log driver that writes container logs to some external logging service so you can easily monitor the jobs.. then that's another good reason to do it. The last (but obvious) advantage is that deploying new software using a docker image instead of messing around on the host is often a winner.

It's a lot cleaner to make one single image containing all the code you need. Then you trigger `docker run` commands from the host's cron daemon and override the command/entrypoint. The container will then die and delete itself after the job is done (you might need to capture the container output to logs on the host depending on what logging driver is configured). Try not to send in config values or parameters you change often so you keep your cron setup as static as possible. It can get messy if a new image also means you have to edit your cron data on the host.

When you use `docker run` like this you don't have to worry when updating images while jobs are running. Just make sure you tag them with for example `latest` so that the next job will use the new image.

Having 12 containers running in the background with their own cron daemon also wastes some memory, but the worst part is that cron doesn't use the environment variables from the parent process, so if you are injecting config with env vars you'll have to hack around that mess (write them do disk when the container starts and such).

If you worry about jobs running parallel there are tons of task scheduling services out there you can use, but that might be overkill for a single docker standalone host.